# How to give local variables as properties to cell editor in editable GridX?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo.gridx

I'm using **Dojo 1.9** with **GridX 1.2**. I'm just configuring the `ComboBox` as editor to the cells in the grid.

I have found the following configuration syntax in the examples:

```
    editor: "dijit/form/ComboBox",
    editorArgs: {
        props: 'store: myStore, searchAttr: "label"'
    }},
```

The problem is, that `props` must be a text that would be parsed. It doesn't accept the object. It means, that I must make `myStore` as global variable, which is something I'd like to avoid.

Is there an alternative way to configure editors in GridX?

Comment: https://github.com/oria/gridx/wiki/How-to-show-widgets-in-gridx-cells%3F

Comment: @Philippe: you mean, using setCellValue ?

Comment: Yes. Assigning the store to the comboBox in that method should work... The store should still be created outside though, so maybe you can make it a property of your grid, like declare.safeMixin(grid, {comboStore : new Memory()})...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**QUICK FIX:**
instead of creating it as global variable, add it to a namespace, which is widely used for these cases. So, while creating the store, add it to particular namespace and use it in `props`.

```
var ns = {}; 
//use this namespace for all objects subject to grid/a particular section/anything
ns.myStore = new Memory({
    data: [
        {name:"Option 1", id:"OP1"},
        {name:"Option 2", id:"OP2"},
        {name:"Option 3Samoa", id:"OP3"}
    ]
});

props: 'store: ns.myStore, searchAttr: "label"'
```

So, therefore we can avoid adding up global objects directly to window object.

**RECOMMENDED FIX:**
In the template string that you pass for that column, instead of using default combo box, use a custom widget.

And in this widget, override the `postCreate` method and set the desired store.

```
define([ 
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dijit/form/ComboBox",
    "dojo/store/Memory"
], function(lang, comboBox, Memory) {
    return dojo.declare("myapp.widget.MyComboBox", [ dijit.form.ComboBox], {
    // summary:
    //Custom sub-class of ComboBox with following functionality:
    //This will set the desired store

    postCreate: function(){
        // summary:
        // This will call default postCreate and additionally create/set store:

        this.inherited(arguments);
        var wid = this;
        //if store is static get storeObj from a json file
        //if store comes from backend, make the call here and get storeObj
        dojo.xhrGet({
            url: "filenameOrUrl",
            handleAs: "json"
        }).then(function(result){
            var storeObj = new Memory(result);
            wid.set("store",storeObj);
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Now you this in the template for that column. **Note that we need not mention the store here neither as string or object, since the widget itself will load the store, once created.**

```
<div data-dojo-type="myapp/widget/MyComboBox" 
    style="width: 100%"
    data-dojo-attach-point="gridCellEditField"
></div>
```